# Como ler um dataLayer?

Tags: javascript

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou precisando levar um dataLayer em meu sistema.
O pessoal que trabalha com Google Tag Manager criou alguns dataLayer e eu preciso resgar algumas informações com o javascript para usar em outros locais.

Como posso realizar uma leitura de um determinado dataLayer e pegar suas informações? 
Exemplo de dataLayer:

```
dataLayer.push({
        'transactionId': '{{mov_vehicle_lead}}',
        'transactionTotal': '{{PProd_Price_AmericanStandard}}',
        'transactionProducts': [{
            'sku': '{{PProd - VehicleID}}',
            'name': '{{PProd_Veiculo}}',
            'category': '{{PProd_Marca}}',
            'price': '{{PProd_Price_AmericanStandard}}',
            'quantity': '{{Quantidade}}'
    }],
    'event': 'transactionComplete'
    });
```

Grato pela ajuda! 
Obrigado!

Comment: Se o `dataLayer` é um array, tanto que adiciona novas entradas a esse array com `push`, terá de utilizar um `for` para percorrer e obter o que quer. Dê um exemplo concreto de algo que quisesse pegar do `dataLayer`

Comment: Por exemplo, gostaria de pegar o valor sku do dataLayer.

Answer (score 2):

Seria algo assim que pensou?
Retorna um array dos skus de transactionProducts (coloquei o name para visualizar melhor).

```js
const skus = (transactionId) => window.dataLayer.forEach(obj => {
  if(obj.transactionId === transactionId) {
    return obj.transactionProducts.map({ sku, name }) => {
      sku,
      name
    });
  }
});
```